# Why does the Seaborn color palette not work for Pandas bar plots?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

An online Jupyter notebook demonstrating the code and showing the color differences is at:
https://anaconda.org/walter/pandas_seaborn_color/notebook

The colors are wrong when I make bar plots using Pandas dataframe method.  Seaborn improves the color palette of matplotlib.  All plots from matplotlib automatically use the new Seaborn palette.  However, bar plots from Pandas dataframes revert to the non-Seaborn colors.  This behavior is not consistent, because line plots from Pandas dataframes **do** use Seaborn colors.  This makes my plots appear to be in different styles, even if I use Pandas for all my plots.

How can I plot using Pandas methods while getting a consistent Seaborn color palette?

I'm running this in python 2.7.11 using a conda environment with just the necessary packages for this code (pandas, matplotlib and seaborn).

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'y':[5,7,3,8]})

# matplotlib figure correctly uses Seaborn color palette
plt.figure()
plt.bar(df.index, df['y'])
plt.show()

# pandas bar plot reverts to default matplotlib color palette
df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()

# pandas line plots correctly use seaborn color palette 
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: *1.* What is your specific question - do you want to know a solution (and possible workaround) or do you want to know the reason for this behavior? *2.* This information may be related to your question: `pyplot.scatter` also does not use seaborn colors (by default?).

Comment: Thanks kazemakase. I've edited the question to clarify that I'd like to know how I can plot using Pandas methods while getting a consistent Seaborn color palette. (Of course, knowing the reason may be helpful to the above.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Credit to @mwaskom for pointing to `sns.color_palette()`. I was looking for that but somehow I missed it hence the original mess with `prop_cycle`.

---

As a workaround you can set the color by hand. Note how the `color` keyword argument behaves differently if you are plotting one or several columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [3, 6, 1, 2], 'y':[5, 7, 3, 8]})

df['y'].plot(kind='bar', color=sns.color_palette(n_colors=1))
```

[image: One column plot]

```
df.plot(kind='bar', color=sns.color_palette())
```

[image: Two columns plot]

My original answer:

```
prop_cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']
df['y'].plot(kind='bar', color=next(iter(prop_cycle))['color'])
df.plot(kind='bar', color=[x['color'] for x in prop_cycle])
```

Comment: You can just do `sns.color_palette()` to get the current color; it's not necessary to do that business with the list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in pandas specifically for bar plots (and boxplots as well I think), which is fixed in pandas master (see the reported [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11614) and the [PR](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/11865) to fix it).
This will be in pandas 0.18.0 which will be released in the coming weeks.

Comment: Joris, This is really helpful and the issue link is informative.  I wish I could choose two answers, but I went with Goyo's because it was immediately useful and seems it will have more potential for longevity in relation to this topic.  Thank you!

Comment: I have also confirmed this answer now.  I have installed the Pandas development version 0.18.0rc1+62.g41b1d25 and this solves the problem.